# how should be this actionscript bytecode?

Tags: actionscript-3, bytecode

I need to improve a method in AS3
I have this function in actionscript:

```
  public function as_setInvites(param1:Object) : void {
     this.messageArea.htmlText = param1.toString();
  }
```

that represent this bytecode:

```
trait method Qname(PackageNamespace(""),"as_setInvites") dispid 0
method
name null
param Qname(PackageNamespace(""),"Object")
returns Qname(PackageNamespace(""),"void")

body
maxstack 2
localcount 2
initscopedepth 16
maxscopedepth 17

code
getlocal_0
pushscope
getlocal_0
getproperty Qname(PackageNamespace(""),"messageArea")
getlocal_1
callproperty Multiname("toString",[PrivateNamespace("-","16"),Pac ..etc
setproperty Qname(PackageNamespace(""),"htmlText")
returnvoid
```

And this is what i need

```
  public function as_setInvites(param1:Object) : void {
     this.messageArea.html = true;
     this.messageArea.wordWrap = true;
     this.messageArea.multiline = true;
     this.messageArea.htmlText = param1.toString();
  }
```

How should be the corrispective bytecode of the following new code?Any tool?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after a while, i think to founf the solution:

> ```
> getlocal_0
> getproperty Qname(PrivateNamespace(""),"messageArea")
> pushtrue
> setproperty Qname(PackageNamespace(""),"html")
> getlocal_0
> getproperty Qname(PrivateNamespace(""),"messageArea")
> pushtrue
> setproperty Qname(PackageNamespace(""),"wordWrap")
> getlocal_0
> getproperty Qname(PrivateNamespace(""),"messageArea")
> pushtrue
> setproperty Qname(PackageNamespace(""),"multiline")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Cool that you found the solution, but for further references use http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/swfinvestigator/

Just compile a swf file and you can retrieve it's bytecode.

Cheers